# Changing mongoengine document inheritance mid project

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using python mongoengine ORM.

Initially I have setup my document to be like this:

```
PropertyRentalData(db.Document):
   base_rent = db.FloatField()
   area = db.FloatField()
   address = db.StringField()
```

and I have saved about 250K collections using that.

```
all = PropertyRentalData.objects()
len(all) #about 250K
```

Now I want to change that it derives from an abstract class, so it'll look like this:

```
PropertyBaseData(db.Document):
   area = db.FloatField() 
   address = db.StringField()


PropertyRentalData(PropertyBaseData):
   base_rent = db.FloatField()


PropertySalesData(PropertyBaseData):
   price = db.FloatField()
```

But now, querying existing PropertyRentalData returns nothing...

```
all = PropertyRentalData.objects()
len(all) #returns 0
```

Any idea on what to do here without requiring me to rebuild my DB from scratch?

Thanks!

Comment: can you connect to mongodb directly and show the structure of the collection?

Comment: Hi Rafael, I am not quite sure what you mean. Do you mind explaining a bit?